# How do I get str.translate to work with Unicode strings?

Tags: python, unicode, string

I have the following code:

```
import string
def translate_non_alphanumerics(to_translate, translate_to='_'):
    not_letters_or_digits = u'!"#%\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'
    translate_table = string.maketrans(not_letters_or_digits,
                                       translate_to
                                         *len(not_letters_or_digits))
    return to_translate.translate(translate_table)
```

Which works great for non-unicode strings:

```
>>> translate_non_alphanumerics('<foo>!')
'_foo__'
```

But fails for unicode strings:

```
>>> translate_non_alphanumerics(u'<foo>!')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in translate_non_alphanumerics
TypeError: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode
```

I can't make any sense of the paragraph on "Unicode objects" in the [Python 2.6.2 docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) for the str.translate() method.

How do I make this work for Unicode strings?

Comment: here's an [example that removes Unicode punctuation from a string using `unicode.translate()` method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11066687/4279).

Comment: better use `import string; string.punctuation` instead of hardcoding `not_letters_or_digits` in real code. I get that here you'd rather be explicit.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The Unicode version of translate requires a mapping from Unicode ordinals (which you can retrieve for a single character with [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord)) to Unicode ordinals. If you want to delete characters, you map to `None`.

I changed your function to build a dict mapping the ordinal of every character to the ordinal of what you want to translate to:

```
def translate_non_alphanumerics(to_translate, translate_to=u'_'):
    not_letters_or_digits = u'!"#%\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'
    translate_table = dict((ord(char), translate_to) for char in not_letters_or_digits)
    return to_translate.translate(translate_table)

>>> translate_non_alphanumerics(u'<foo>!')
u'_foo__'
```

*edit:* It turns out that the translation mapping must map from the Unicode ordinal (via `ord`) to either another Unicode ordinal, a Unicode string, or None (to delete). I have thus changed the default value for `translate_to` to be a Unicode literal. For example:

```
>>> translate_non_alphanumerics(u'<foo>!', u'bad')
u'badfoobadbad'
```

Comment: Thank you!  (Such a dumb design decision to have an identically named function that operates differently.)

Comment: Also, if you don't want to manually define the punctuation chars:  import string; translate_table = {ord(unicode(c)) for c in string.punctuation}

Note: This will not translate all the special unicode punctuation characters (there are tons...)

Comment: your `not_letters_or_digits` is missing '$' and '&'. Let me suggest using `string.punctuation` instead of hardcoding the set or characters

Answer (score 7):

In this version you can relatively make  one's letters to other

```
def trans(to_translate):
    tabin = u'привет'
    tabout = u'тевирп'
    tabin = [ord(char) for char in tabin]
    translate_table = dict(zip(tabin, tabout))
    return to_translate.translate(translate_table)
```

Answer (score 5):

I came up with the following combination of my original function and [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66502/mike-boers)'s version that works with Unicode and ASCII strings:

```
def translate_non_alphanumerics(to_translate, translate_to=u'_'):
    not_letters_or_digits = u'!"#%\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'
    if isinstance(to_translate, unicode):
        translate_table = dict((ord(char), unicode(translate_to))
                               for char in not_letters_or_digits)
    else:
        assert isinstance(to_translate, str)
        translate_table = string.maketrans(not_letters_or_digits,
                                           translate_to
                                              *len(not_letters_or_digits))
    return to_translate.translate(translate_table)
```

**Update**: "coerced" `translate_to` to unicode for the unicode `translate_table`.  Thanks Mike.

Comment: I would suggest that you coerce the translate_to into Unicode for the Unicode version, otherwise the translate call will freak out if you pass it a Unicode string, and "normal" string.

Comment: This seems like something that should be part of the language. +1

Answer (score 4):

For a simple hack that will work on both str and unicode objects,
convert the translation table to unicode before running translate():

```
import string
def translate_non_alphanumerics(to_translate, translate_to='_'):
    not_letters_or_digits = u'!"#%\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'
    translate_table = string.maketrans(not_letters_or_digits,
                                       translate_to
                                         *len(not_letters_or_digits))
    translate_table = translate_table.decode("latin-1")
    return to_translate.translate(translate_table)
```

The catch here is that it will implicitly convert all str objects to unicode,
throwing errors if to_translate contains non-ascii characters.

Answer (score 1):

I had a unique problem compared to the others here.  First I knew that my string possibly had unicode chars in it.  (Thanks to Email on Mac...) But one of the common chars was the emdash AKA u"\u2014" character which needed to be converted (back) to two dashes AKA "--".  The other chars that might be found are single char translations so they are similar to the other solutions.

First I created a dict for the emdash.  For these I use a simple string.replace() to convert them.  Other similar chars could be handled here too.

```
uTranslateDict = {
    u"\u2014": "--", # Emdash
}
```

Then I created a tuple for the 1:1 translations.  These go through the string.translate() builtin.

```
uTranslateTuple = [(u"\u2010", "-"),  # Hyphen
                   (u"\u2013", "-"),  # Endash
                   (u"\u2018", "'"),  # Left single quote => single quote
                   (u"\u2019", "'"),  # Right single quote => single quote
                   (u"\u201a", "'"),  # Single Low-9 quote => single quote
                   (u"\u201b", "'"),  # Single High-Reversed-9 quote => single quote
                   (u"\u201c", '"'),  # Left double quote => double quote
                   (u"\u201d", '"'),  # Right double quote => double quote
                   (u"\u201e", '"'),  # Double Low-9 quote => double quote
                   (u"\u201f", '"'),  # Double High-Reversed-9 quote => double quote
                   (u"\u2022", "*"),  # Bullet
]
```

Then the function.

```
def uTranslate(uToTranslate):
    uTranslateTable = dict((ord(From), unicode(To)) for From, To in uTranslateTuple)
    for c in uTranslateDict.keys():
        uIntermediateStr = uToTranslate.decode("utf-8").replace(c, uTranslateDict[c])
    return uIntermediateStr.translate(uTranslateTable)
```

Since I know the format of the input string I didn't have to worry about two types of input strings.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to specify all the characters that need to be replaced, you could also view it the other way around and, instead, specify only the valid characters, like so:

```
import re

def replace_non_alphanumerics(source, replacement_character='_'):
    result = re.sub("[^_a-zA-Z0-9]", replacement_character, source)

    return result
```

This works with unicode as well as regular strings, and preserves the type (if both the `replacement_character` and the `source` are of the same type, obviously).

Answer (score 0):

I found that where in python 2.7, with type `str`, you would write

```
import string
table = string.maketrans("123", "abc")
print "135".translate(table)
```

whereas with type `unicode` you would say

```
table = {ord(s): unicode(d) for s, d in zip("123", "abc")}
print u"135".translate(table)
```

In python 3.6 you would write

```
table = {ord(s): d for s, d in zip("123", "abc")}
print("135".translate(table))
```

maybe this is helpful.