# What is producing "TypeError character mapping must return integer..." in this python code?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, typeerror

please, can someone help me with the code bellow?
When I run it the logs said:

```
return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CG\Documents\udacity\rot13serendipo\main.py", line 51, in post
    text = rot13(text)
  File "C:\Users\CG\Documents\udacity\rot13serendipo\main.py", line 43, in rot13
    return st.translate(tab)
TypeError: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode
   INFO     2012-04-28 20:02:26,862 dev_appserver.py:2891] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I know the error must be in rot13(). But when I run this procedure in the IDE it works normally.

Here my code:

```
import webapp2

form= """
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Unit 2 Rot 13</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Enter some text to ROT13:</h2>
    <form method="post">
      <textarea name="text"
                style="height: 100px; width: 400px;"></textarea>
      <br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>

  </html> """

def rot13(st):
    import string
    tab1 = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    tab2 = 'nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM'
    tab = string.maketrans(tab1, tab2)
    return st.translate(tab)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(form)

    def post(self):
        text = self.request.get("text")
        text = rot13(text)
        self.response.out.write(text)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                          debug=True)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I cannot reproduce with your code and your input (using 64-bit EPD Python 2.7.2 on Linux). Perhaps you could include a small complete example that fails for you and that we could experiment with?

Comment: Thanks, aix. I think Andrew discovered the cause. (the text is being entered as unicode). Do you know how I fix that?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's probably because the text is being entered as unicode:

```
>>> def rot13(st):
...     import string
...     tab1 = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
...     tab2 = 'nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM'
...     tab = string.maketrans(tab1, tab2)
...     return st.translate(tab)
... 
>>> rot13('test')
'grfg'
>>> rot13(u'test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in rot13
TypeError: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode
>>>
```

This question covers what you need:

- [How do I get str.translate to work with Unicode strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324067/how-do-i-get-str-translate-to-work-with-unicode-strings)

If you are sure that unicode strings aren't important I guess you could just:

```
return str(st).translate(tab)
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. You have helped me very, very much.