# Decoding Base64 String in Python 2 & pass to PIL?

Tags: python, base64, python-imaging-library

I'm currently using the following line in Python 3 to decode a base64 string and pass it to PIL as an image:

```
img = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(imageData)))
```

However when I try it in Python 2 I get :

```
TypeError: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode
```

How can I decode it and pass it to PIL in python2?

More Info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/Me/Desktop/Project/app.py", line 43, in predict
image = decodeImageFromBase64String(imageData)
File "/Users/Me/Desktop/Project/app.py", line 84, in decodeImageFromBase64String
img = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(imageData)))
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 112, in urlsafe_b64decode
"""
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 71, in b64decode
if altchars is not None:
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 36, in _translate
return s.translate(''.join(translation))
```

Comment: Could you include the full back trace?

Comment: Sure. Just updated my answer.

Comment: Your `imageData` is probably `unicode`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367302/what-is-producing-typeerror-character-mapping-must-return-integer-in-this-p

Comment: Hehe you're right a simple ```.encode('ascii')``` did the trick. Feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `imageData` has probably been converted to unicode at some point. `urlsafe_b64decode` passes `str` values (aka `bytes`) as *altchars* and so the translation in `b64decode` expects `str` data as input.

```
def urlsafe_b64decode(s):
    """Decode a string encoded with the standard Base64 alphabet.

    s is the string to decode.  The decoded string is returned.  A TypeError
    is raised if the string is incorrectly padded or if there are non-alphabet
    characters present in the string.

    The alphabet uses '-' instead of '+' and '_' instead of '/'.
    """
    return b64decode(s, '-_')
```

Re-encode your `imageData` or fix the source not to decode it as `unicode`.

Here's an example of how `b64decode` and `urlsafe_b64decode` behave differently on receiving `unicode`.

```
>>> base64.b64encode('tervehdys')
'dGVydmVoZHlz'
>>> s = unicode(base64.b64encode('tervehdys'))
>>> base64.b64decode(s)
'tervehdys'
>>> base64.urlsafe_b64decode(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "base64.py", line 112, in urlsafe_b64decode
    return b64decode(s, '-_')
  File "base64.py", line 71, in b64decode
    s = _translate(s, {altchars[0]: '+', altchars[1]: '/'})
  File "base64.py", line 36, in _translate
    return s.translate(''.join(translation))
TypeError: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode
```