# Pyspark Dataframes: Does when(cond,value) always evaluate value?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

so I am trying to conditionally apply an udf some_function() to column b1, based on the value in a1. (otherwise don't apply). Using *pyspark.sql.functions.when(condition, value)* and a simple udf

```
some_function = udf(lambda x: x.translate(...))    
df = df.withColumn('c1',when(df.a1 == 1, some_function(df.b1)).otherwise(df.b1))
```

With this example data:

```
|    a1|    b1|
---------------
|     1|'text'|
|     2|  null|
```

I am seeing that some_function() is always evaluated (i.e. the udf calls translate() on null and crashes), regardless of *condition* and applied if *condition* is true. To clarify, this is not about udfs handling null correctly, but when(...) always executing *value*, if *value* is an udf.

Is this behaviour intended? If so, how can I apply a method conditionally so it doesn't get executed if *condition* is not met?

Comment: Why do you say that _"It seems like some_function() is always evaluated"_?

Comment: You are right, it is always executed, regardless of the condition given in when(). changed the question to make this more clear.

Comment: No I mean how do you know it's always executed?

Comment: In this example some_function() will throw an exception if x == null. (cannot call translate() on null). In my dataset there is no a1 == 1 with b1 == null, BUT there is a1 != 1 with b1 == null. I've udpated the question.

Comment: Ok I was able to reproduce your issue, but I do not believe it's because translate is being called on null. Try this: `some_function = udf(lambda x: str(x).translate(...))`. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367302/what-is-producing-typeerror-character-mapping-must-return-integer-in-this-p) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324067/how-do-i-get-str-translate-to-work-with-unicode-strings).

Comment: Today I found out that there's a function [`pyspark.sql.functions.translate()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.translate) that should do what you want without using a `udf`.

Comment: So I was wrong. I ran into the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634651/using-udf-ignores-condition-in-when) myself and it turns out that this is a result of the optimizer doing batch processing for python `udf`s. My solution of converting to `str` probably worked because it converted the value `null` into the string `"null"`. In any case, your `udf` has to be robust to handle bad inputs, or use the builtin `pyspark.sql.functions.translate()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using UDF ignores condition in when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634651/using-udf-ignores-condition-in-when)

Comment: So the answer is: udfs are always executed when used in when(), regardless of condition. So make them robust enough, and make sure the execution does not cause side effects.

Comment: I can't say for sure "always executed" but the rest is accurate.