# Creating score column in Pyspark data frame using jellyfish package

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, duplicates, string-matching, record-linkage

I have a data frame like this

```
df = [id1, id2, name1, name2, address1, address2, DOB1, DOB2]
```

I would like get **Jaro_winkler** score (in a new column) for the column1 and column2 in the Pyspark DataFrame. I am trying to use **jellyfish** python package.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This response stems mainly from viewing a similar question in StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56025726/pyspark-how-to-deal-with-null-values-in-python-user-defined-functions).  In their example, they investigate how null values can be dealt with when running a jellyfish string comparison.

You'll want to set up a UDF call to utilize the parallel processing powers of pyspark.  See code below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
import jellyfish

# initiate user defined function (UDF) call.
@udf(DoubleType())
def jaro_winkler(s1, s2):
    return jellyfish.jaro_winkler(s1, s2)

# to create a new column
df = df.withColumn('new_column',jaro_winkler(col('column1'),col('column2')))

# to show top 20 results
df.select('new_column').show()
```

for a similar functionality with the option to deal with null values, I would suggest altering your function to incorporate the following change:

```
@udf(DoubleType())
def jaro_winkler(s1, s2):
    if s1 is None or s2 is None:
        out = 0
    else: 
        out = jellyfish.jaro_winkler(s1, s2)
    return out
```