# PySpark Error when Using Jellyfish Functions: str argument expected

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working on a task getting the similarity score of the name related data. I am using Spark and jellyfish function in Python. Below is my code in a class:

```
import jellyfish
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, DataFrame
from pyspark import SparkContext

df = self.jaro_winkler_func(df, 'df1.first_name', 'df2.first_name')

def jaro_winkler_score(self, s1, s2):
    if s1 is None or s2 is None:
        out = 0
    else:
        out = jellyfish.jaro_winkler(s1, s2)

    return out

def jaro_winkler_func(self, df, column_left, column_right):
    df = df.withColumn('test', self.jaro_winkler_score(df[column_left], df[column_right]))

    return df
```

Below is the error I got:

```
out = jellyfish.jaro_winkler(s1, s2)
TypeError: str argument expected
```

I see other related posts in below for same issue but above functions used are already borrowing the answers from these posts.

[Creating score column in Pyspark data frame using jellyfish package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61754964/creating-score-column-in-pyspark-data-frame-using-jellyfish-package)

[Pyspark: How to deal with null values in python user defined functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56025726/pyspark-how-to-deal-with-null-values-in-python-user-defined-functions)

I am using Spark 2.3.

Please suggest and thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not passing `str`, did you define `jaro_winkler_score` as a `UDF`? The first link from the posts you've provided explains it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It worked after defining jaro_winkler_score as a UDF.